# Ver valores de FormData

Tags: javascript

¿Como puedo imprimir con console.log los valores que capturo en un FormData antes de enviarlo a un servicio por URL? .

Lo estaba intentando de esta manera:

```
e.preventDefault();
var form = $('#frmSede')[0];
var formdata = new FormData(form);
var oEstado = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("estado"));
console.log("El estado es: " + oEstado);
```

Y la consola de deveploment tools me arroja esto: El estado es:

```
[object FormData]
```

Necesito saber que valores tierne para agregar una logica antes de pasarlo a mi servicio.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify), cual Convierte un objeto de javascript a una cadena `JSON`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var objeto = { un_dato_importante: '¡Felices fiestas a todos!' };

console.log( 'A pelo: ' + objeto );
console.log( 'Con JSON.stringify: ' + JSON.stringify( objeto ) );
```

También puedes usar en tu caso [FormData.get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get)

Ejemplo:

```js
var form = new FormData();
form.append('datos', 'si es un dato');
console.log( form.get('datos') );
```